# Black band with 100% width gets a gap when table gets min-width

Tags: html, css

I have a band on top and a table on the bottom.

When the table is without min-width the band (with 100% width) works perfectly covering 100% of the screen, however, when I add the min-width:950px to the table I get a gap I can't get rid of on the right side of the screen whenever the screen resizes to a smaller size.

I've looked around but I haven't been able to fix it with any of the recommendations here. Any help appreciated

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xxVUW/

```
#band{width:100%;height:100px;background: black;}
#port-content{min-width:950px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear exactly what you're asking. If you mean to say that by adding a table width, the "band" div no longer matches the width of the table, then all you need to do is set the width of the "band" div to be equal to the width of the table.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xxVUW/2/

```
#band{min-width:950px; width:100%;height:100px;background: black;}
#port-content{min-width:950px; border:1px solid red;}
```

EDIT: Added "min-width" attribute to "band" class

Comment: it almost is what you're saying (I'll update my answer) except I need the black band to be 100% width to cover the entire screen all the time so it can't match the table's width

Comment: I added the "min-width" attribute to the "band" class. That should allow it to be at least 950px, but also stretch to 100% if the page width is larger.